# How to estimate Black Scholes parameters using Maximum Likelihood estimate method

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-merton

It might be a naive question but I'm new to finance. I've been trying to get my head around this question from a long time and still totally clueless about this.

Suppose that the observed jumps in three consecutive months are 0, 1, 2 times. How to find the estimated parameters λ̂ of the Black-Scholes-Merton model using maximum likelihood estimate method.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2):

The jumps are modeled as an independent Compound Poisson Process. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38358130_Maximum_Likelihood_Estimation_of_a_Compound_Poisson_Process)'s a paper (Leopold Simar: *Maximum Likelihood Estimation of a Compound Poisson Process* in The Annals of Statistics 4(6) November 1976) that describes how to get MLE for such process